# Dynamic creation of Table type

Tags: hana

I have a column table with a single column.

I would like to create a table type with all the elements in the column of the above mentioned table as column names with fixed datatype and size and use it in a function.

similarly like below:

[Dynamic creation of table in tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174738/dynamic-creation-of-table-in-tsql)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT:

To finish a product, a machine has to perform different Jobs on the material with different tools.

I have a list of Jobs a machine can perform and a list of Tools. a specific tool for a specific Job.

Each job needs a specific tool and number of hours (to change the tool once it reached its change time). A Job can be performed many times on a product. (in this case if a Job is performed for 1 hour = tool has been used for 1 hour)

For each product, a set of tools will be at work in a sequence. so I Need a report for each product, number of hours the tool has worked.

EDIT 2:

Product table

```
---------+-----+
ProductID|Jobs |
---------+-----+
 1       | job1 |
 1       | job2 |
 1       | job3 |
 1       |  .   |
 1       |  .   |
 1       |100th |
 2       | job1 |
 2       |  .   |
 2       |  .   |
 2       |200th |
```

Jobs table

```
-------+-------+-------
Jobs   |  tool | time
-------+-------+-------
 job1  |tool 10| 2
 job1  |tool 09| 1
 job2  |tool 11| 4
 job3  |tool 17| 0.5
```

required report (this table does not physically exist)

```
----------+------+------+------+------+------+-----
productID | job1 | job2 | job3 | job4 | job5 | . . .
----------+------+------+------+------+------+------
1         | 20   |  10  |  5   |  .   |   .  | .
----------+------+------+------+------+------+------
2         | 10   |  13  |  5   |  .   |   .  | .
----------+------+------+------+------+------+------
```

Comment: That sounds like a not-so-clever sledge-hammer approach for something. What is that "something"? If you explain the use case a bit there might be a better option for that.

Comment: Hi Lars Br. Added additional Information why i needed it.

Comment: Ok, I've read your added requirement. But what do you need to create a table for in this case? Why can't you join JOBS with TOOLS and aggregate the times?

Comment: For each product - how many hours per Job/tool Needs to be reported. the first coulmn will be productID. The time varies according to the shape of the metal placed for the product. The suggestion you have give is anyways to be done for the Jobs and tools Aggregation.

Comment: Maybe you can provide the table definitions you have right now, some test data and what the output should look like. Based on the description I don't see why your data structures should by dynamic.

Comment: Thanks Lars Br. Table info Added! The list of Jobs changes machine to machine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the added information, there are two main requirements here:

1. You want to sum up the time spent for producing each product grouped by the jobs involved
   and
2. You want to have a cross-table report showing the times from step 1 against products and jobs.

For the first bit, you probably could do this with a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    p.product_id,
    j.jobs,
    SUM(j.time) as SUM_TIME
FROM 
   products p
 INNER JOIN jobs j
 ON p.jobs = j.jobs  
GROUP BY  
    p.product_id,
    j.jobs;
```

For the second part: this is usually called a PIVOT report.
SAP HANA does not provide a dynamic SQL command for generating output in this form (other DBMS have that).
However, this dynamic transformation is usually relevant for the data presentation and not so much for the processing.

So, as you probably want to use some form of front end for this report (e.g. MS Excel, Crystal Reports, Business Objects X, Tableau, ...) I would recommend doing the transformation and formatting in the frontend report. Look for "PIVOT" or "CROSSTAB" options to do that.

Comment: Thanks Lars, I understood HANA doesnt not provide PIVOT. I Need this representation for processing further. whats the best practice in writing sqls. wrirting stored procedures and fucntions or pure SQL script? To make life easy i am writing stored procedures and fucntions but they consume a lot of time. I would like to your opinion and take some suggestions.

Comment: Can you share what your processing requirements are? Using a crosstab as an input to some further processing is rather uncommon in my experience as it's more about optical representation for the human reader and less about what one can do with the data.

Comment: PAL in hana requires crosstab Format.